# Connect servo motor to 8255

Tags: microcontroller, servo, proteus

I want to control servo motor with the help of 8086 processor and thus want to connect 8255 with servo motor (with help of some motor driver) . Most of the information on internet is about stepper motor and i didn't found any useful stuff related to my problem . Please help me in figuring in out how to connect servo motor and 8255 . (i mean i want to design in Proteus software , in which servo is connect to 8255 through some drive (or directly if possible)).

I guess we need to find device which can produce pulse with modulation and then connect it to servo .I am not able to run even basic circuit . I guess if i will be able to run this then i am done . Does any one knows the settings or i am using wrong pulse generator ?second screenshot is motor properties and first one pulse generator properties.
Edit : I am accepting Justme answer but i will love to get more ideas and suggestions .so if any one else want to share something please do.

[image: pulse generator]

[image: motor properties]

[image: basic circuit which i am trying to run]

Comment: @jsotola https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomotor

Comment: I believe we know what a servo motor is. I'll rephrase: which servo motor you mean from all servo motors in the world? Hobby servo? What kind of interface the servo has?

Comment: @Justme it is named as  motor-servo in Proteus

Comment: @jsotola it is named as motor-servo in Proteus

Comment: OK, so you have Proteus and we don't, why not read the documentation how it works? However, If I had to make an enlightened guess, it simulates a standard hobby servo. Getting it to work however with just 8086 and 8255 will be a pain. Since you don't have a timer, you must output the servo pulse position signal using timed loops.

Comment: @Justme  i am trying to run the motor simply by connect it to power and pulse because after that i will get the whole idea , wait i will just attach screen shot

Comment: @Justme added few screen shots . Please help

Comment: Well what is your question that needs answering. I will write one, but "please help" is not a question that has an answer. Your servo timings are extremely incorrect by the way, so it does not work. Have you researched how servos work, or need a quick answer how to drive a servo? Edit: Ah, you do have a question there now.

Comment: the second screenshot seems to be the motor properties ... cannot be sure because you ate providing unclear information ... try supplying a pulse train of 50 Hz ... each pulse width needs to be between .5 ms and 4 ms

Comment: @jsotola Does 4m means 4 milliseconds (4 ms) ? Program didn't work when i supplied 50 Hz

Comment: @jsotola yes second screenshot is motor properties

Comment: @jsotola I was using analog signal (see screen shot ) that's why it was not running .Now it is after using digital signal .

Comment: @jsotola can you recommend some pwm servo which can produce upto 20 NM torque   ? I guess connections will be same just voltage required will be different

Comment: @jsotola How do we control minimum and maximum angle of motor in Proteus ?

Comment: look at your screenshots

Comment: @jsotola yeah , i mean i want to control the minimum and maximum angle from 8255 . But there is no pin for controlling the angle .It is in setting of motor . Also in real world the motor we buy , we have to set these settings of motor or are these settings  programmable ?

Comment: i think that you need to google `servo motor tutorial` ... your question shows that you need to absorb more information

Comment: @jsotola   Yes , i will look for more tutorial but can you tell how we will fix min and max angle in servo motors in real world ?

Comment: @jsotola i watched tutorials of servo and i think i have understood just tell me one thing please : is setup of servo motor which can provide specific torque similar to the one in screenshots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drive a servo you send it pulses every 20ms or so, and the pulse width determines the servo angle. 1ms pulse makes it go all the way to one end, and 2ms pulse makes it go the other end. 1.5 ms pulse should set it to the middle position. The pulse lengths are not that exact, each model will vary but those are good starting points.

Basically, in Proteus, you should be able to connect that servo directly to 8255 PPI.

Comment: can you please tell specific values to fill in setting it's not working for values provided in comments and in answer

Comment: second screen shot is motor properties

Comment: I was using analog signal (see screen shot ) that's why it was not running .Now it is after using digital signal .

Comment: I am accepting this answer but i will love to get more ideas and suggestions .so if any one want to share something please do.

Comment: can you recommend some pwm servo which can produce upto 20 NM torque   ? I guess connections will be same just voltage required will be different

Comment: No, because suggesting what to buy is off-topic and I would not know what to suggest. Also your requirement is 10 to 100 times larger than hobby servos typically have, so you might not find any 20 Nm servos that work with similar PWM control.

Comment: How do we control minimum and maximum angle of motor in Proteus through 8255 .There is no pin connected to motor for controlling the angle . It is in setting of motor .  Also in real world the motor we buy , we have to set these settings of these are programmable ?

Comment: Please take a look at your own screenshots and you may find the min and max control settings. Servos you buy are not configurable so for fine-tuning you just need to find what pulse widths it actually works with and then send only those pulse widths.

Comment: can you tell how we will fix min and max angle in servo motors in real world .Here we are fixing through settings of motors but how we will do in real world since it does not have any external pins for that . Servo motor stops after rotating angle specified in settings

Comment: Yes, there are no pins and so it is not possible and it can't be done. You cannot change the servo you buy. You can change the signal you send to it.

Comment: so this implies that amount of angle a servo can rotate is fixed when we buy them ?

Comment: i watched tutorials of servo and i think i have understood just tell me one thing please : is setup of servo motor which can provide specific torque similar to the one in screenshots ?